# Get datatable and filling model from it

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable, object-oriented-analysis

In my project i have a fill method.

```
  public IList<MyModel> Fill(DataTable dt)
    {
        IList<MyModel> IProperty = new List<MyModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            MyModel Property = new MyModel
            {
                Name= dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
                Surname = dt.Rows[i]["Surname"].ToString(),
                Age = dt.Rows[i]["Age"].ToString(),
            };
            IProperty.Add(Property);
        }
        return IProperty;
    }
```

It fill my model from datatable. But i must write this fill method for all model. I dont want to write this method all the time. I need a solution for this. I'm open to any kind of proposal

Not:I dont want to use Entity framework or other ORM frameworks.

Comment: There is no magic way that works for all types. Maybe reflection but i would strongly recommend against it.

Comment: What would change between different implementations of Fill?

Comment: IProperty and Property type will change. And Datatable value will change.

Comment: If DataTable values change too, you should really just make separate implementations for each returned type. It would do wonders to readability of your code in comparison to any possible single method solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make sure the field names and properties of the object with the same name, try this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Fill<T>(DataTable dt)
    where T : new()
{
    return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
    {
        var obj = new T();
        var properties = 
            from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            join c in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() on p.Name equals c.ColumnName
            select new {p, c};
        foreach (var item in properties)
            item.p.SetValue(obj, row[item.c]);
        return obj;
    });
}
```